# Woman in red from The 100 connection to Matrix

Tags: reference, the-matrix, the-100

I've noticed that in the Matrix, the woman in red was part of the simulated program, meant to catch attention and appear harmless. The 100 woman in red appears to be serving a similar purpose, it is part of a program and it does appear harmless so far.

Was the "woman in red" character inspired by Matrix or at least is there any similarity/connection?

Answer (score 2):

There is some speculation, but producer [Javi Grillo-Marxuach said](https://twitter.com/OKBJGM/status/690530271192420353) there is no connection between ALIE's (Lady in Red) VR City of Light, and the Matrix Blue/Red Pill.

[image]

Then we get things like:
[image]

It's hard to imagine that the entire Season 3 plot isn't somewhat inspired by the Matrix, but [the Matrix isn't the first to do that in general](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DownTheRabbitHole). [His tumblr says the same](http://okbjgm.tumblr.com/post/141583731276/there-are-alot-of-comparisons-between-the-matrix):

[image]

The similarities may be superficial, as Women/Lady in Red are common ideas. See the disambiguation pages for both [The Woman in Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman_in_Red) and [The Lady in Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady_in_Red), or [any study on the Red Dress Effect](http://www.adweek.com/news/advertising-branding/well-buy-nearly-anything-woman-red-dress-159146):

> So potent and enduring is the “Red Dress Effect” that behavioral psychologists have studied it—and demonstrated that women who don red are not only regarded by men as more physically and sexually attractive, but also tend to have more money spent on them. In fact, the dating site OKCupid discovered that women wearing red in their profile photos have a greater statistical chance of being asked out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my theory.

The pill form of the AI is the first version of the matrix, hence the blue emblem. It was *imperfectly* made by its creator. We never, ever, see the creator of the matrix in the movies. In fact, we know that the movie is the **third** version of the matrix from inception and hasn't been updated since. We know that the matrix reinvents itself after each cycle. We also know that the original two matrices existed in the real world *conjoined* to the false world. We know the original creator made it as a place without human suffering.

So in short, the 100 is the begining of all this. My prediction is that, to beat Allie 1, who struck first and destroyed the world, answers the question who shot first from the movies, and by the way, the 100 will use the *second* matrix. Once in the second matrix, the "commander" will inform clarke that the AI is linked to the whole planet via the internet and solar panels.

Unfortunately, the second matrix is not a perfect place either. In the second attack, the 100 and grounders use AI 2 to launch ancient weapons to block the sky. This was all part of AI1 plan all along as her conciousness will merge with the commander's when it finally is upgraded. With both the sentient and computer based AIs in Matrix 2, it becomes unstable, exposing the first 'Neo', and showing the one now known as the gate keeper and creator the flaw with the first two matrices. That humans die *without* suffering and the AI will die without humans.

The show ends with the first humans being put into battery pods as well as a few select people who refuse the first pill being imprisoned (so to speak) in Zion by the AI. The matrix itself then utilizes 'latent memory' to rebuild civilization in a light where humans exist *eternally* at the point prior to the AI being created.

Ultimately, the two become symbiotic and one not being able to live without the other. This show is or easily can be used to explain all the things the Matrix movies never did. Hence why the second AI looks like the tracker they pull out of Neo. Now Neo is the residual conciousness of all the previous human commanders that never desired for humanity to be stuck in such a limbo. The **agents** on the other hand are the first 'chipped' people from the *first* matrix who are now *completely* part of the matrix.

Hence why agents can take anyone's body at will-- only if they are submissive just like Allie, saying how she can't get past 'free will'. Neo, Morpheus, and Trinity are in fact the central feature continued out forever, because Morpheus is the reemergence of the human Version of the Chancellors; Trinity the commanders of the 100; and Neo the commanders of grounder nation. The mountain men are the last members of the people from the Mad Max films.

So my theory is as such. Mad Max series is the prequel, Matrix Series the finale, and The 100 to give the whole thing a linking storyline from apocalypse to eternal life. The Mad Max link is easier to see, blood-bags in mount weather, reapers made by the blood-bag leadership, radiated soil and massive wastelands. Also Charlize Theron's charcter at the end easily can be seen as the first leader of the grounders after the banishment of the mutated mountain men relatives.

Comment: Is there any chance to introduce some paragraph blocks into this wall of text in order to encourage people to even *try* to read it? Noone is really going to read a stream of conciousness.